# Calculation of Total seconds from a particular format of time

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to calculate total seconds of **'33 hr 40 mins 40 secs'** in asp.net c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're given a string of the format `"33 hr 40 mins 40 secs"`, you'll have to parse the string first.

```
var s = "33 hr 40 mins 40 secs";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, "\d+");
var hr = Convert.ToInt32(matches[0]);
var min = Convert.ToInt32(matches[1]);
var sec = Convert.ToInt32(matches[2]);
var totalSec = hr * 3600 + min * 60 + sec;
```

That code, obviously, has no error checking involved. So you might want to do things like make sure that 3 matches were found, that the matches are valid values for minutes and seconds, etc.

Answer (score 14):

```
new TimeSpan(33, 40, 40).TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 2):

Separate hour, minute and seconds and then use

***Edited***

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(33,40,40);

/* Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole 
   and fractional seconds. */
double totalSeconds = ts.TotalSeconds;
```

Read [TimeSpan.TotalSeconds Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds.aspx)

Comment: this won't work. `TimeSpan.Parse` only handles hours up to 23, and will throw an OverflowException for this

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    // Calculate seconds in string of format "xx hr yy mins zz secs"
    public double TotalSecs(string myTime)
    {
        // Split the string into an array
        string[] myTimeArr = myTime.Split(' ');

        // Calc and return the total seconds
        return new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(myTimeArr[0]),
                            Convert.ToInt32(myTimeArr[2]),
                            Convert.ToInt32(myTimeArr[4])).TotalSeconds;

    }
```