# Convert specified format of time to a date asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hii,

I have time, for e.g **33 hr 40 mins 50 secs** . i would like to convert it to a date time format.

for e.g I have used Convert.ToDateTime("33:40:50"), but in this case when you converting to date time, hour should be less than 24, otherwise it will fire an exception. Pls help me to solve the above problem.

Comment: Exact duplicate of own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048053/calulation-of-total-seconds-from-a-particular-format-of-time

Answer (score 2):

Try [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).[Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx):

> a time interval specification of the form: `[ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]`